# Spring Integration - Missing Messages while routing to multiple channels

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration and working out an example to send message from single channel to multiple channels, in this perspective using Redis message store for each channel with the intention of not losing any messages. The requirement is to send message to the channels  - replyChannel, mailChannel and dbChannel. Currently the code just prints the sysout statements and has no major functionality.

To check if the messages are being routed correctly, I have written a java test class to send 15 messages.

Checking the output I find that some of the messages are being lost. Also there isn't any exceptions that are being displayed.

Thank you for all the support.

### Below is the sample code:

### **config.java** - has all the integration configurations

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel replyQueueChannel () {    return new QueueChannel (new MessageGroupQueue(redisMesageStore(),replyQueue, 1000));    }  

@Bean
public MessageChannel mailQueueChannel () {    return new QueueChannel (new MessageGroupQueue(redisMesageStore(),mailQueue, 1000));    }            

@Bean
public MessageChannel auditlogQueueChannel () {     return new QueueChannel (new MessageGroupQueue(redisMesageStore(),auditLogQueue, 1000));    }
```

### Java code where the messages are being sent to the channels

```
@Override
@ServiceActivator (inputChannel="dbQueueChannel", poller =@Poller(fixedDelay="10", taskExecutor="dbServiceExecutor"))
public void executeDBConditions (Message<DeferredModel> deferredMsg) {
replyQueueChannel.send(deferredMsg);        
auditlogQueueChannel.send(deferredMsg);
mailQueueChannel.send (deferredMsg);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step is always to enable DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`; you will see lots of debug messages showing the message flow.

You can also monitor redis with `redis-cli` and the `monitor` command to track the redis activity.

If you can't figure out what's happening using those techniques, post the logs someplace like a github gist or pastebin etc.

**EDIT**

Here's a working version of your scenario; I had no problems with "missing messages". Since you don't show your full application, I can't tell why you are having trouble with yours.

I also added a version using a `RecipientListRouter` configured in Java - but you should really have asked that as a new question rather than piggy-backing on this one...

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessageEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Router;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.redis.store.RedisChannelMessageStore;
import org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupQueue;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.PollableChannel;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@SpringBootApplication
public class So34628789Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So34628789Application.class, args);
        MessageChannel foo = context.getBean("foo", MessageChannel.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            foo.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo" + i).build());
        }
        getOutput(context);

        // now with an RLR...

        foo = context.getBean("routedMessageChannel", MessageChannel.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            foo.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo" + (i + 15)).build());
        }
        getOutput(context);

        context.close();
    }

    private static void getOutput(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        int n = 0;
        PollableChannel out = context.getBean("replyQueueChannel", PollableChannel.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            Message<?> received = out.receive(10000);
            if (received != null) {
                System.out.println(received);
                n++;
            }
        }
        out = context.getBean("mailQueueChannel", PollableChannel.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            Message<?> received = out.receive(10000);
            if (received != null) {
                System.out.println(received);
                n++;
            }
        }
        out = context.getBean("auditlogQueueChannel", PollableChannel.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            Message<?> received = out.receive(10000);
            if (received != null) {
                System.out.println(received);
                n++;
            }
        }
        Assert.state(n == 45, "expected 45 messages");
    }

    @Autowired
    private JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyQueueChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(new MessageGroupQueue(redisMessageStore(), "replyQueue", 1000));
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mailQueueChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(new MessageGroupQueue(redisMessageStore(), "mailQueue", 1000));
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel auditlogQueueChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(new MessageGroupQueue(redisMessageStore(), "auditLogQueue", 1000));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisChannelMessageStore redisMessageStore() {
        return new RedisChannelMessageStore(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel foo() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo fooService() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel routedMessageChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

// Router Technique 1
//  @Bean
//  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="routedMessageChannel")
//  public RecipientListRouter router() {
//      RecipientListRouter router = new RecipientListRouter();
//      List<Recipient> recipients = new ArrayList<>();
//      recipients.add(new Recipient(replyQueueChannel()));
//      recipients.add(new Recipient(mailQueueChannel()));
//      recipients.add(new Recipient(auditlogQueueChannel()));
//      router.setRecipients(recipients);
//      return router;
//  }

    @MessageEndpoint
    public static class Foo {

        @Autowired
        private MessageChannel replyQueueChannel;

        @Autowired
        private MessageChannel mailQueueChannel;

        @Autowired
        private MessageChannel auditlogQueueChannel;

        private List<MessageChannel> channels;

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="foo")
        public void sendIt(Message<String> deferredMsg) {
            replyQueueChannel.send(deferredMsg);
            auditlogQueueChannel.send(deferredMsg);
            mailQueueChannel.send (deferredMsg);
        }

        // Router Technique 2
        @Router(inputChannel="routedMessageChannel")
        public List<MessageChannel> route(Message<?> message) {
            if (this.channels == null) {
                this.channels = Arrays.asList(new MessageChannel[] { this.replyQueueChannel, this.mailQueueChannel,
                        this.auditlogQueueChannel });
            }
            return this.channels;
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT2**

There are two techniques to create a router in Java configuration.

Consuming endpoints declared in XML create 2 beans - a message handler and a consumer. When using JavaConfig any `MessageHandler` `@Bean` can be annotated with `@ServiceActivator` to create the corresponding consumer.

Or, you can use a POJO method annotated with `@Router`.

I have updated the sample above to show the other technique. Again it works fine for me.

You can find the complete project [on github here](https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/tree/master/SO34628789).

As I said, if you are losing messages somehow you should use debug logging as well as the `redis-cli` monitor command to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Yes. I tried enabling DEBUG and using monitor - but I couldn't understand the flow of messages correctly.

Comment: Seems that this process of sending messages via channels is not actually routing the messages to all the channels. So the channel that gets the message first is actually processing the message. Also to achieve this I tried RecipientListRouter using xml and this gives me the required result  - broadcasting the messages to all the specified channels.

Comment: Can any help be provided how the xml configuration for RecipientListRouter can be coverted to java configuration.                         
 The Sample xml configuration is provided below:                                         <int:recipient-list-router id="recptListRouter" input-channel="routingChannel">
   <int:recipient channel="replyQueueChannel"/>
   <int:recipient channel="auditlogQueueChannel"/>
   <int:recipient channel="mailQueueChannel"/>
  </int:recipient-list-router>

Comment: See the edits; you should really have asked the "how to configure a RecipientListRouter in Java" as a separate question since it's unrelated to this one.

Comment: Would ensure this is followed from next time.

Comment: I am little confused at the usage of the java configuration for RecipientListRouter. Can the input channel be specified as ServiceActivator                                                                                                   @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="routedMessageChannel")
    public RecipientListRouter router() {.....}

Comment: The RecipientListRouter - with the channels having MessageStore  - is not sending the message to all the channels. The functionality is working fine without the MessageStore.  I would sure the share the link for github.

Comment: Please find the github link [link](https://github.com/SRekha-LV/SISamples/tree/master/SpringRulesApplication). I am new to this to handle, if there is anything else please let me know so that going forward will take care. Thank you.

Comment: The application is a spring restful webservice appliaction. The class  **TestAsyncCalls** in test/java has the code to test the url. The service url would print the sysout statements passing through each channel. 

I have tested the message passing through channels for 150 requests and could find that the messages are missing. Hence trying out for different options, checked for RecipientListRouter which didn't help me.

Comment: I figured out that the MessageStore was actually causing the issue. If the message store is removed, then all the messages were getting printed. 

Also when the message store is given the message routing is being considered as point - to- point even if the **RecipientListRouter** is configured and the message is processed by the channels which receives it first. When the message store is not given, the multiple channels are being treated as publisher-subscribers and the messages are not missed.

Please guide.

Comment: There's no such class (and no test/java). I suggest you start with my example - that works fine with the router and the message store. `redis-cli` with `monitor` shows the redis activity.